# Invoking Text Transformation in VS Extension

Tags: visual-studio, templates, t4, template-engine, t4-toolbox

I want to create a Visual Studio Item Template that generates an Item (for eg. custom .aspx page) in the solution by executing T4 Template while adding it to the solution. For this I am using this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586947.aspx
    Can anyone tell me how to get a Service Provider, which is mentioned in the code in above link. To solve this I wrote :

> EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
>   // Get a service provider – how you do this depends on the context:
>
> > IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider(dte as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider);

But Its giving me an arguement null exception error, because variable dte remains null. Why is it null? I don't know whether I am doing it right or wrong. Please suggest how do I implement serviceprovider given in the code in above link so that I could move ahead. If possible please provide me a code example.

Please suggest,

Thanks,
Mayur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to directly query for STextTemplating using GetGlobalService in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Thanks Garath, Can you please provide me some code or any example project. I have done what you suggested but still I am getting value of ITextTemplating T4 as null. The code I have written is as follows :
IServiceProvider serviceProvider = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as IServiceProvider;
ITextTemplating t4 = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;

Comment: Even I tried : ITextTemplating t4 = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(STextTemplating)) as ITextTemplating;

** If possible plz provide me some code or link which will help me get out of this...

Comment: I'm wondering, are you using VS2008?  I seem to remember that Package.GetGlobalService didn't work so well in that version.

Comment: NO... I am using Visual Studio 2010... And It's not working for it.

Comment: Can you try casting the automation object provided to  IWizard.RunStarted to IServiceProvider and using that?

Comment: No Not yet. Can you provide me some code by trying it at your end?

Answer (score 0):

Can it be due to the different assembly versions I have used in this project. The application I am developing is in VS2010, and I tried to use the assemblies with the versions 10.0.0 and for which the RunTime version is 4.0. But there are few dlls which I couldn't find with the version 10.0.0.0 and RunTime Version as v4.0. Is it the thing which is annoying me? I tried to add new dlls with the required versions but I don't have these dlls with version 10.0 and also I didn't get it anywhere on net. If thats the reason then plz let me know where I will get those dlls...? The dlls I have used are as follows :

1. Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop, vesrion : 7.1.40304.0, RunTime Version : v1.1.4322
2. Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version : 10.0.0.0, RunTime Version : v4.0.30319,
3. microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.8.0, Version : 8.0.0.0, RuntimeVersion : v1.1.4322
4. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizardInterface, Version : 8.0.0.0, Runtime Version : v2.0.50727
5. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating, Version : 9.0.0.0, Runtime Version : v2.0.50727
6. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0,
   Version : 10.0.0.0,
   RunTime Version : v4.0.30319
7. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.VSHost.10.0,
   Version : 10.0.0.0,
   RunTime Version : v4.0.30319

Please suggest...

Comment: It certainly would stop it working, you should find the 10 versions of all of them in the Visual Studio SDK (download from microsoft.com) under VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0